# PyInstaller and PySide and QtGui

Tags: pyside, pyinstaller

I'm having a similar problem to the post:

[Pyinstaller: ImportError: cannot import name QtGui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335722/pyinstaller-importerror-cannot-import-name-qtgui)

... however this post does not appear to have a solution. I cannot use pyinstaller to install the very simply PySide script (helloWorld.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
label = QtGui.QLabel("Hello Plain World")
label.show()
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

I run:

```
]$ ./makespec.py -F helloWorld.py
]$ pyinstaller helloWorld.Spec
```

which generates:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
20 INFO: UPX is not available.
34 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
103 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
104 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
156 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
245 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
308 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
316 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
599 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with /home/derek/BitBucketRepos/tmp/qvt/pyinstaller/tmp
599 INFO: checking Analysis
599 INFO: building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc non existent
599 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
632 INFO: Analyzing /home/derek/BitBucketRepos/tmp/qvt/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader    /_pyi_bootstrap.py
643 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
652 INFO: Processing hook hook-site
661 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
726 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
727 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
780 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
871 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
939 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
1272 INFO: Processing hook hook-pydoc
1358 INFO: Processing hook hook-email
1398 INFO: Processing hook hook-httplib
1430 INFO: Processing hook hook-email.message
1476 INFO: Analyzing /home/derek/BitBucketRepos/tmp/qvt/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader    /pyi_importers.py
1515 INFO: Analyzing /home/derek/BitBucketRepos/tmp/qvt/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader    /pyi_archive.py
1542 INFO: Analyzing /home/derek/BitBucketRepos/tmp/qvt/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader    /pyi_carchive.py
1570 INFO: Analyzing /home/derek/BitBucketRepos/tmp/qvt/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader   /pyi_os_path.py
1573 INFO: Analyzing helloWorld.py
1575 INFO: Processing hook hook-PySide
1575 INFO: Hidden import 'codecs' has been found otherwise
1575 INFO: Hidden import 'encodings' has been found otherwise
1575 INFO: Looking for run-time hooks
objdump: section '.dynamic' mentioned in a -j option, but not found in any input file
2579 INFO: Using Python library /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
2579 INFO: Adding Python library to binary dependencies
2964 INFO: Warnings written to /home/derek/BitBucketRepos/tmp/qvt/pyinstaller/tmp/build    /helloWorld/warnhelloWorld.txt
2968 INFO: checking PYZ
2968 INFO: rebuilding out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing
2968 INFO: building PYZ (ZlibArchive) out00-PYZ.toc
3329 INFO: checking PKG
3329 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
3329 INFO: building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
objdump: section '.dynamic' mentioned in a -j option, but not found in any input file
10614 INFO: checking EXE
10614 INFO: rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because helloWorld missing
10614 INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
10614 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /home/derek/BitBucketRepos/tmp/qvt/pyinstaller     /tmp/dist/helloWorld
```

This successfully produces an executable but when I run it I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name QtGui
```

My system is Linux Mint 15 (ubuntu 13.04), have PySide and PySide-dev installed and used quite a bit, I am using pyinstaller 2.0.

Any help would be GREATLY appricated.

Derek

Comment: I didn't have any trouble packaging PySide applications with [**cx_Freeze**](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to hidden imports that the analysis cannot detect. From the manual:

> If Analysis thinks it has found all the imports, but the app fails
>   with an import error, the problem is a hidden import; that is, an
>   import that is not visible to the analysis phase. Hidden imports can
>   occur when the code is using **import** or perhaps exec or eval. You
>   get warnings of these (see Build-time Messages). Hidden imports can
>   also occur when an extension module uses the Python/C API to do an
>   import. When this occurs, Analysis can detect nothing. There will be
>   no warnings, only a crash at run-time. To find these hidden imports,
>   set the -v flag (Getting Python's Verbose Imports above). Once you
>   know what they are, you add the needed modules to the bundle using the
>   --hidden-import= command option, by editing the spec file, or with a hook file (see Using Hook Files below).

Try adding the following to your spec file's Analysis section:

```
hiddenimports=['PySide.QtCore','PySide.QtGui']
```

Comment: I've the same probblem and adding the hidden imports does not help.