# PyQt5 failing import of QtGui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I've just moved from PyQt4 to 5 and I'm having an issue with QtGui.  I installed using the 32bit windows installer, not my own build.

when I do:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
```

I get

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, UI.MainUI.Ui_MainWindow):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QMainWindow'
```

so I tried

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QtGui
```

Which results in:

```
ImportError: cannot import name QtGui
```

then I tried to change the sys.path according to [Pyinstaller: ImportError: cannot import name QtGui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335722/pyinstaller-importerror-cannot-import-name-qtgui) work around but it still gives me the same

```
ImportError: cannot import name QtGui
```

*Update:* It looks like I do in fact import QtGui because when I go in IDLE and try it, it still autocompletes QMovie and a whole bunch of other attributes.  Is there any reason QMainWindow just wouldn't be in there?  (It's not, neither is QDialog and they seem important)

Comment: suggest setup your Dev Environment using Anaconda for newbie. please [follow my article](https://suiwenfeng.tk/pycharm-intigrated-with-pyqt5anaconda.html) step by step.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Assuming everything was installed correctly, you need to adjust your imports slightly to port from PyQt4 to PyQt5.

The main GUI elements are in the QtWidgets module, whilst the more basic GUI elements are in QtGui. See the [Qt modules page](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmodules.html) for more details.

The example code needs to be changed to something like:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, UI.MainUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    ...
```

For more details on porting from PyQt4 to PyQt5, see: [Differences Between PyQt4 and PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html).

Comment: More than appreciated, I spent far too long on this for such an easy answer.

Comment: `QApplication`  (of, e.g.,  `app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)`
   `app.exec_()`) has also been moved to QTWidgets.