# Python Import error cannot import name QtGui in PyQt5 Ubuntu 16

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, ubuntu-16.04

I am working on a `pyqt5` project in `Ubuntu16.04`. To install `pyqt5`, I used the command `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`. In `Ubuntu16.04`, `python3.5` comes preinstalled so initially I designed everything with `python3.5`. Application was running fine.

Later I upgrade the `python3.5` to `python3.6` using below steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

After the installation, I made sure that running `python3` is invoking the `python3.6` and not `python3.5`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2

sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

After this if I type in python3, it launches `python3.6`.

Then I reinstalled all the python packages I required using `sudo pip3 install <name>` (this time it was getting installed in python3 (python3.6).  After this when I ran my application, it started giving me below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtGui'
```

With python3.5 it was working perfectly fine but with python3.6 it started showing this error. How can I resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Can help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20752155/5532710

Comment: @CarloZanocco I think the linked question is different for what I have. Thanks

Comment: Can you go into the python3.6 directory, find pip, and run it directly from here to install the package? Probably you has missed to change pip link?

Comment: @CarloZanocco Actually I didn't installed `pyqt5` using pip. I installed it using `apt-get install python3-pyqt5`. Installing it using pip was giving me errors. When I looked into those errors online, I found out that I had to install specific version which is `pip3 install pyqt5==5.14.0`. After that it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the I went into this issue because I upgraded the python3 from 3.5 to 3.6 so I believe some path got messed up and it wasn't able to locate the pyqt5 properly.

I installed `pyqt5` using `apt-get install python3-pyqt5`. So I installed it using pip:

`pip3 install pyqt5==5.14.0`

and it worked fine.